# Throw InterruptedException when using parallelStream - Java

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, interrupted-exception, forkjoinpool

I have a method with nested for loops as follows:

```
public MinSpecSetFamily getMinDomSpecSets() throws InterruptedException {
    MinSpecSetFamily result = new MinSpecSetFamily();
    ResourceType minRT = this.getFirstEssentialResourceType();
    if (minRT == null || minRT.noSpecies()) {
        System.out.println("There is something wrong with the "
                + "minimal rticator, such as adjacent to no species. ");
    }
    for (Species spec : minRT.specList) {
        ArrayList<SpecTreeNode> leafList = this.getMinimalConstSpecTreeRootedAt(spec).getLeaves();
        for (SpecTreeNode leaf : leafList) {
            result.addSpecSet(new SpecSet(leaf.getAncestors()));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This works fine, but the application is performance critical so I modified the method to use `parallelStream()` as follows:

```
public MinSpecSetFamily getMinDomSpecSets() throws InterruptedException {
    ResourceType minRT = this.getFirstEssentialResourceType();
    if (minRT == null || minRT.noSpecies()) {
        System.out.println("There is something wrong with the "
                + "minimal rticator, such as adjacent to no species. ");
    }

    MinSpecSetFamily result = minRT.specList.parallelStream()
            .flatMap(spec -> getMinimalConstSpecTreeRootedAt(spec).getLeaves().parallelStream())
            .map(leaf -> new SpecSet(leaf.getAncestors()))
            .collect(MinSpecSetFamily::new, MinSpecSetFamily::addSpecSet, MinSpecSetFamily::addMSSF);
    return result;
}
```

This worked fine until I wanted to introduce an `InterruptedException` in the 'getLeaves()' method. Now the `parallelStream` version will not compile as it says I have an unreported `InterruptedException` which must be caught or declared to be thrown. I think this is because the `parallelStream` runs on multiple threads. No combination of try/catch blocks suggested by my IDE resolves the issue.

The second solution posted in [Interrupt parallel Stream execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243559/interrupt-parallel-stream-execution)
suggests that I may be able to resolve the issue using `ForkJoinPool` but I have been unable to figure out how to modify my method to use this approach.

Comment: An `InterruptedException` is a checked exception, hence the compilation issue. It does not actually matter that you are running this in parallel, you need a way to pass this exception from inside the stream to outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to your current design, you just need to catch the exception:

```
.flatMap(spec -> {
     try {
       return getMinimalConstSpecTreeRootedAt(spec).getLeaves().parallelStream();
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       // return something else to indicate interruption
       // maybe an empty stream?
     }
 }).map(...)
```

Note that a parallel stream of parallel streams is possibly unnecessary and parallelising the top level stream only may be sufficient performance-wise.

Comment: There is an extra ) after parallelStream in your answer, but thanks, this did the job. Also, I changed the second parallelStream to .stream() as suggested.

Comment: On second thoughts, this does not fix the issue. If I return null in the catch block, the thread continues running for each additional 'spec'. Can I jump out of the parallelStream and return null from the whole method if any spec is null?

Comment: @SteveW you may be able to throw an unchecked exception (but I'm not 100% sure if it will stop the whole stream though and it feels a bit hacky). It sounds like you may be better off using a different design, for example with an ExecutorService: submit the tasks and store the futures, then call `.get()` on the futures and do your thing. If any task gets interrupted you will know it and be able to stop the processing.

Comment: OK, that comment is a bit over my head. But if you are suggesting manually creating the required threads, I don't think I can do that. I replaced a nested for loop (which is inherently serial) with parallelStream and got a 50% speed improvement. If I don't use parallelStream I'm probably better off reverting to nested for loops as far as I can see.